# C#: write the output of a void function into a text box

Tags: c#, textbox, monodevelop, gtk#

I m a beginner and I'm developing a gtk# project in monodevelop.

I have a void function that prints out some stuff (like 0x01, 0x00). And I want them to be shown in a text box. However, I cant just add the output of the function to a TextBox.Text  So what should I do?

Comment: what you mean by `" Output of a void function"`?

Comment: Where does the function writes the output? Why you "cant just add the output of the function to a TextBox.Text"?

Comment: I cant see a function. Provide the code you've written.

Comment: You can use textBox1.AppendText.

Comment: since its a void function. I cant just add to .Text directly/

Answer (score 2):

You need to access that TextBox inside your function. and then you need to change the Text property to the value that you need as an output of function.
Example:
(say the name of your TextBox is Textbox1)

```
void func()
{
    Textbox1.Text = "your value";
}
```

Comment: But OP said "However, I cant just add the output of the function to a TextBox.Text"

Comment: Probably because his method does not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 1): Make the method return a value, for example a `string` and use the calling code to show the result in a `TextBox`:

```
string TheMethod(...)
{
    string result = "";

    ...

    result = someValue;
    return result;
}

void CallIt()
{
    textBox1.Text = TheMethod(...);
}
```

Alternative 2): Assign the value of the `TextBox` within your method:

```
void TheMethod(...)
{
    ...

    textBox1.Value = TheValueToDisplay;
}
```

Usually alternative 1) is more preferrable, because it allows you to easily separate the logic from the UI. If a method that only calculates stuff has connections to the UI, you can not easily put it into another module, like a DLL for example. It's generally a good idea to separate code that doesn't really *need* the UI from code that is purely UI.

Comment: Thanks every one. The problem is that I m using the function as a dll. The function itself is in c++ code( in another solution). And I call it in the c# projects. Its out out is like -- value[0]=0x51;value[1]=0xa3; printf("0xvalue[0]") printf("0xvalue[1]"). I was thinking if there is a way to access the variables from c++ code in my c# project

Comment: Omg i didnt realize we can use a function to return a string. Thankks

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer helpful, feel free to upvote or accept it.